# How do run reload() and open() in Atom-Shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

1) Is this javascript call not supported on Atom-shell?
window.open('#/openpage','_self',false)

2) In NodeJS-Webkit, I could either reload the HTML with win.reload() without the toolbar and buttons. Is Atom-shell support this API as well?

3) In the app.js that is program to index.html into the Atom-shell

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
```

and index.html tried to execute a reload command and failed that BrowserWindow is not defined.

```
BrowserWindow.reload()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`browser-window` only works in the Browser process (i.e. the one your app starts in). Try this:

```
var remote = require('remote');
remote.getCurrentWindow().reload();
```

Comment: Awesome! The remote module can do a lot more, make sure to check out the docs

Comment: I still have no idea how to run similar code with window.open(...) in Atom-Shell?

Comment: current version of electron needs:

    require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow().reload();

Answer (score 0):

For Reload :

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote
BrowserWindow.getCurrentWindow().reload();
```

For Close:

```
BrowserWindow.getCurrentWindow().on('close', () => {
  // window was closed...
})
```

Documentation :
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/remote